# Why am I not able to import object from django models in python 3?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I am converting my python 2 project into python 3 & during conversion I am facing some strange problem like I am not able to import object from my django models.

[image: Error_msg]

I think I have imported them properly but still I am getting error.

Comment: Not sure because the traceback was hidden, but maybe it's circular import issue, maybe..

Comment: Please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce your problem. You are not even showing the complete error.

Comment: What does mean by circular import issue ?

Comment: @Moon This may be of help: https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: I have searched for circular dependancy & it looks like you are right. It may conflicting each other.Thanks for suggestion.